# Delete file from desktop in single User mode osx

Tags: macos, bash, file

My start up disk is full and the mac is not booting i want to to remove file from desktop in single user mode

I tried this

```
rm -rf /users/username/desktop/filename
```

but not working it says files read only

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As described in this article [mac-wont-boot-full-disk](http://www.curphey.com/blog/2012/10/24/mac-wont-boot-full-disk/) you need to mount you disk in RW mode :

```
sudo /sbin/mount -uw /
```

then you'll be able to remove what you want